# How do I customize C compile and run in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compilation, vscode-code-runner

I have always compiled and run my C project manually in this way:

```
gcc -o main file1.c file2.c main.c
./main
```

If I open my project on VS Code and try to compile and run it by pressing the "play" button, VS Code first writes on terminal:

```
gcc main.c -o main
```

which will make obviously fail the compile, because the other needed files (file1.c and file2.c) are missing in compilation.

Where (on VS Code) can I customize the compile and run process made by the "play" button from the Code Runner extension?

Comment: You need to create a project and add file1.c, file2.c and main.c to the project.

Comment: @user3386109 they are in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For customizing the Code Runner play button, [modify your `code-runner.executorMap` setting](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration).

But I'd instead recommend a build task, since Code runner is more suited to building and running individual files, and by editing the executor map for a specific set of files would kind of be subverting its purposes, whereas this kind of thing is what build tasks are designed for.

A build task for you might look something like this:

```json
{
   "type": "shell",
   "label": "C/C++: gcc build main",
   "command": "gcc",
   "args": ["-o", "main", "file1.c", "file2.c", "main.c"],
   "options": {
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
   },
   "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
   "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
   },
}
```

See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_tutorials.